# google visualization api, identify tableid in response function

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Hmmm, maybe someone can help me out here or point me in the right direction , as i have been banging my head against the wall for a number of days now and dont seem to be gettin anywhere useful.
(and admittedly i'm pretty new with regards to json,objects, google visulization etc)
essentially, i am running 3 different queries on the same page against 3 different fusion tables, which in return are supposed to return an array of 3 different xets of markers.
all is fine, when i run the queries individually and make an array of the markers .
however, running the 3 queries on the same page, i can't seem to find a way to identify the query in the response function.

any hints much appreciated. and i'll be happy to provide more info if needed (tried to get rid of some unneccessary stuff)

this is what i have. thanks

a) calling the function "setFusionData()" with all relevant vars. something like setFusionData("'LatLng','name'", 2729461);
(this is calles 3 times with different variables)

```
            function setFusionData(selColumns,tableId) {
              /****
                 an actual query example is this:
                http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tqx=reqId:1234&tq="select+'LatLng','name'+from+2729461"
              ****/

              var query = new google.visualization.Query(
                  'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tqx=reqId:1234&tq='+ encodeURIComponent("SELECT "+selColumns+" FROM "+tableId+"")
              );  

              query.send(getFusionData);  //do something with the response    
            }


            function getFusionData(response) {

                /**             
                here, is the problem as i need to get the table id or reqId or anything that is uniquely passed on from "setFusionData" above
                also something like
                alert(JSON.stringify(response)) does not return any reqId or table id either
                ***/


                /*return rows/columns  and add values to an array of markers***/    
                    var numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
                    var numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns(); 
                    for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {                     
                        /* add markers to array etc this  works fine***/    
                    }



            }
```

i also tried something like this:

```
function setFusionData(selColumns,tableId) {
......  
    query.send(getFusionData({reqId:tableId}));
}


function getFusionData(response) {
    alert(response['reqId']);//returns tableId. but how do i get the tableData ?

}
```

with wich i can get the reqId, but not the table*Data*. So I am only able to get either id  or data :(

----edit----------------

after messing around a bit more (see below) it appears that the key/value pairs that get returned when typing the query into the browser directly are different than what gets returned by the call from the script...i.e the following

```
            http ://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tqx=reqId:1234&tq="select+'LatLng','name'+from+2729461"
```

typed directly into the browser bar will return

```
            version:'0.5',reqId:'1234',status:'ok',table etc
```

however, calling the same from within the script returns something like

```
                {
                "rj":"0.5","ef":"ok","pb":[],"qb":[],"h":"{"cols":
                        [{"id":"col2","label":"LatLng","type":"string"},{"id":"col1","label":"name","type":"string"}],
                    "rows":
                        [{"c":[{"v":"47.20572,12.70414"},
                    {"v":"Hohe Tauern"}]},{"c":[{"v":"47.5530395,12.925611"},{"v":"Berchtesgaden"}]},{"c":[{"v":"47.5585405,14.61887"},{"v":"Gesu00e4use"}]}],
                        "p":{"totalrows":3}
                    }"
                }
```

, so no 'reqId' but only some cryptic keys (without one that looks like the reqId either)...... anyone any idea why that would/could be ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can figure it out by just looking at the JSON response, your sample request returns:

```
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({
    version:'0.5',
    reqId:'1234',
    status:'ok',
    table: {
      ...
    }
})
```

You already got `response.reqId` to identify which request is this the response for, now you can use `response.table` to create a new [`DataTable`](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#DataTable) instance:

```
var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(response.table);
```

Or, since you have multiple tables, put then in an array indexed with the `reqId`

```
tables[response.reqId] = new google.visualization.DataTable(response.table);
```

You'd do `var tables = new Array()` before calling `setFusionData()` for the first time.

Comment: hmm, i am probably a bit dense (very likely). i tried the following :
[code]function getFusionData(response) {
var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(response.reqId);
alert(JSON.stringify(dt))
}
[code]
but i only get cols/rows/p(whatever that is) but no reqID

Comment: i messed around a bit more, but in the end, it boils down to , that response.table returns 'undefined' because 'response' actually returns something like this 
`{
"rj":"0.5",
"ef":"ok",
"pb":[],
"qb":[],
"h":"
 {\"cols\":
  [{\"id\":\"col2\",\"label\":\"LatLng\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"id\":\"col1\",\"label\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"}],
 \"rows\":
  [{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"47.20572,12.70414\"},
 {\"v\":\"Hohe Tauern\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"47.5530395,12.925611\"},{\"v\":\"Berchtesgaden\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"47.5585405,14.61887\"},{\"v\":\"Ges\\u00e4use\"}]}],\
  "p\":{\"totalrows\":3}
 }"
}`

Comment: Replace google.visualization.DataTable(response.reqId) with google.visualization.DataTable(response.table) and it should work.

Comment: hmm, i tried that too (and other permutation) but when using `query.send(getFusionData({reqId:tableId}));`
i get 
`function getFusionData(response){
 var ri=response.reqId);//returns reqId
 var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(response.table);//returns table obj but with zero results
}`
when using `query.send(getFusionData);`
i get
`function getFusionData(response) {
 response.getDataTable();//returns all the right table rows/cols etc
 response.reqId;//undefined as 'reqId' does not exist in response (see above)
}`
i MUST be missing something but cant find it. thanks for the help though